# How to pass multiple strings through a function to str.format()

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

What is wrong with my application of `str.format` for `my_xpath` below?

```
def look_for(thing, value):
    my_xpath = "//h2[. = '{thing_placeholder}']/following::table//td[. = '{value_placeholder}']"
    my_xpath.format(thing, value)
    return my_xpath

look_for("MyThing", "MyValue")
```

...it doesn't work, instead throws a `KeyError` when `my_xpath` is applied to find a web element.

Or if I try this variant instead, it's not complaining about KeyError, but I'm getting `None` back:

```
def look_for_v2(thing, value):
    my_xpath = "//h2[. = '{thing_placeholder}']/following::table//td[. = '{value_placeholder}']"
    my_xpath.format(thing_placeholder = thing, value_placeholder = value)
    return my_xpath

look_for_v2("MyThing", "MyValue")
```

Comment: You're missing the return statements in your functions

Comment: Ok, just thought that "getting None back" might've been because of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strings are immutable, `str.format` creates a new string and returns it, it does not modify the original string. you must assign the format to a new string and return it or something.  other than that your second way was correct ..

```
my_new_xpath = my_xpath.format(thing_placeholder = thing, value_placeholder = value)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Yes, that was pretty obvious now looking back. My fault for looking at examples and assuming they were complete lines.

Answer (score 1):

Check out documentation for [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

According to docs we should pass key-value based arguments, or dictionary:

`str.format(*args, **kwargs)`:

```
my_xpath = "//h2[. = '{thing_placeholder}']/following::table//td[. = '{value_placeholder}']"
new_xpath = my_xpath.format({'thing_placeholder':thing, 'value_placeholder': value})
```